# offie-js Word Web Add-in: Possible add dynamically menu items

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I'm develop a Microsoft Word add-in with office-js.
One requirement is to add items in a menu at runtime.
The menu can exists in a context menu or ribbon.

I need this to get settings from a Web-service and show this in a menu.

During my research I found some blogs that says it is not possible. But theese are min 3 years old.

Thanks for your help.

Best reagards,
Denny

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it is currently not possible to add menu items at runtime. But its a good idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks. 
I suggest it. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/42390958-support-dynamic-menu-items-in-a-ribbon-or-context